# How to view the stored procedure code in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am new to SQL Server. I am logged into my database through SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a list of stored procedures. How do I view the stored procedure code?

Right clicking on the stored procedure does not have any option like `view contents of stored procedure`.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to "modify" it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Right click on the stored procedure and select **Script Stored Procedure as | CREATE To | New Query Editor Window / Clipboard / File**.

You can also do **Modify** when you right click on the stored procedure.

For multiple procedures at once, click on the **Stored Procedures** folder, hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to open the Object Explorer Details pane, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click to select all the ones that you want, and then right click and select **Script Stored Procedure as | CREATE To**.

Comment: I prefer the 'Script stored procedure as CREATE' instead of 'Modify' when I am just looking at the procedure so I don't accidentally change the procedure.

Answer (score 174):

I guess this is a better way to view a stored procedure's code:

```
sp_helptext <name of your sp>
```

Comment: This approach works best when the results are displayed to text ([Ctrl+T keyboard shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)).

Comment: @FlorinDumitrescu - I prefer to leave it in grid mode and do the following which is extremely fast and is now 2nd nature for me: sp_helptext YourSPName, F5, click the header column "Text", ctrl-c, click anywhere in query, ctrl-a, ctrl-v, ctrl-home, ctrl-r. The reason I like this is I get syntax highlighting and I don't have to scroll to the beginning of the file. (And it's slightly better than ctrl-t because it doesn't prepend the file with "text ---------------".)

Answer (score 46):

The option is called `Modify`:

Click on **Database --> Programmability --> Stored Procedure** .

Here you can right click any of the stored procedures, and click modify.

Be extra careful not to modify it, when you only want to view it!

[image: SSMS 2019]

This will show you the T-SQL code for your stored procedure in a new query window, with an `ALTER PROCEDURE ...` lead-in, so you can easily change or amend your procedure and update it

Comment: If modify is disabled? I do not have permissions to modify

Answer (score 22):

This is another way of viewing definition of stored procedure

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'Your_SP'))
```

Comment: the above one will not give the entire procedure script

Comment: @Smart003, yes it does. If you have difficulties having all characters to be displayed as a grid result refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms

Comment: Thanks - very useful when repository locked for update/processing.

Answer (score 15):

Use this query:

```
SELECT object_definition(object_id) AS [Proc Definition]
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='P'
```

Answer (score 14):

`exec sp_helptext 'your_sp_name'` -- don't forget the quotes

In management studio by default results come in grid view. If you would like to see it in text view go to:

```
Query --> Results to --> Results to Text
```

or `CTRL + T` and then Execute.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers that recommend using the object explorer and scripting the stored procedure to a new query editor window and the other queries are solid options.

I personally like using the below query to retrieve the stored procedure definition/code in a single row (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014, but looks like this should work with SQL Server 2008 and up)

```
SELECT definition 
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourSchemaName.yourStoredProcedureName')
```

More info on sys.sql_modules:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql

Comment: Seems to be the best solution since every other approach will mangle long lines in definition. However it does not account for renamed modules:

```
create procedure dbo.SpRenameDemo as
go
exec sp_rename @objname=N'dbo.SpRenameDemo' , @newname=N'SpRenameDemo_Oops';
go
select * from sys.sql_modules where object_id=object_id(N'dbo.SpRenameDemo');
select * from sys.sql_modules where object_id=object_id(N'dbo.SpRenameDemo_Oops');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can view all the objects code stored in the database with this query:

```
    USE [test] --Database Name
SELECT
    sch.name+'.'+ob.name AS       [Object], 
    ob.create_date, 
    ob.modify_date, 
    ob.type_desc, 
    mod.definition
FROM 
     sys.objects AS ob
     LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS sch ON
            sch.schema_id = ob.schema_id
     LEFT JOIN sys.sql_modules AS mod ON
            mod.object_id = ob.object_id
WHERE mod.definition IS NOT NULL --Selects only objects with the definition (code)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have permission to 'Modify', you can install a free tool called "SQL Search" (by Redgate).  I use it to search for keywords that I know will be in the SP and it returns a preview of the SP code with the keywords highlighted.

Ingenious!  I then copy this code into my own SP.

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way :

```
SELECT object_definition(object_id)
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='p' and name='SP_Name'
```

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for. I have multiple stored procedures in server and local databases. I'm using this query to re-create the stored procedures. ```SELECT name,object_definition(object_id)
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='p' and name LIKE'sp_%'```