# SQL query for opening proc in new query window - SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

So if I want to open a table through query I usually do like

```
select * from databaseschema.dbo.tablename
```

and it displays the results in results window at the bottom of New Query window where I have typed the query.

If I want to open a proc, I have to go to that schema, open stored procedures, right click on proc and click modify which is when it opens in new query window in SSMS.

I want a statement (like mentioned in the first paragraph) where I don't have to do the manual selection through my mouse searching for the proc manually (mentioned in second paragraph) and I can just run the statement and it will open the proc in a new query window.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view the stored procedure code in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733088/how-to-view-the-stored-procedure-code-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `object_definition(object_id)`

```sql
use databaseName;
select name, object_definition(object_id) 
from sys.procedures
where name = 'procedureName'
```

don't forget to replace databaseName and procedureName by the real value

Edit : I check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it seems syntax is

```sql
 SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'procedureName')) AS [Object Definition];
```

Comment: it shows me the results in results pane. 2 columns. column NAME shows me the proc name. 2nd column which has header (No Column Name) shows me - Batch submitted through debugger and so on.......

Comment: Strange, it does work with my version of sql server. I checker [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it seems syntax is `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'procedureName')) AS [Object Definition]; `